# PROLOG File Stream Manipulation; term extraction for processing

Tags: file, io, stream, prolog

I'm working on a case-based reasoning
subsystem for academic advising that is
able to take a new student profile (transcript)
and compare it to database of student_profiles in
order to find the best match if not the exact match.

I'm still not very familiar with the language and
I trying to open a file and extract
an specific predicate  let's say

```
student_profile/4 : student_profile(L1, name, L2, L3)
```

which is found in `student.pl`.

Once I have extracted the predicate from the .pl file, I want to be
able to assign it to a variable and split it
so I can extract the first argument (in this case `L1`) to
make some calculations.

This is what I have so far:
I have opened the file and I'm able to see the entire list of predicates
found in the student profile or transcript.

```
load :- open('h:/AAS/Novel_Profiles/vivian.pl', read, Stream),
        read(Stream, X),
        read_data(Stream, X, StudentP),
        write(StudentP),
        close(Stream).
        
read_data(_Stream, end_of_file, []) :- !.

read_data(Stream, X, [X|StudentP]) :-
    read(Stream, Y),
    read_data(Stream, Y, StudentP).
```

I have looked for examples on how to extract a term and use it for further processing but I have had no luck (or maybe I'm not using the right terminology).

Answer (score 1):

Your `load` predicate should 'return' the list read, or cache it with assertz, for later use...

```
load(StudentData) :- open('h:/AAS/Novel_Profiles/vivian.pl', read, Stream),
        read(Stream, X),
        read_data(Stream, X, StudentData),
        write(StudentP),
        close(Stream).
```

then you can use member/2 to match some record in loaded list...

```
?- load(L),
   member(student_profile(Student, vivian, L2, L3), L),
   writeln(vivian(Student, L2, L3)).
```

But there is a simpler way: `consult` the file and directly query the data.

```
load :- consult('h:/AAS/Novel_Profiles/vivian.pl').
```

Both methods (read or consult), require your file is syntactically correct. Your Prolog will inform you of any problem the file could have.

After a successful consult, each fact (or rule) is ready to use...

```
?- student_profile(Student, vivian, L2, L3),
   writeln(vivian(Student, L2, L3)).
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, would it be the case that the same procedure would apply if I want to query the data from within the program? Like adding something like this before closing the stream member_sp(StudentPred,StudentData), and of course defining such at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, interpreters like Prolog use REPL (Read,Eval,Print,Loop) as a general method for program development.

Comment: Thanks for you help, just one more thing I would like to ask. It might seem very simple but I don't quite understand. Once I have read the file; the data I need has the form of a compound term: [student_predicate([2d vector],vivian,[taken(courses),...],[])|_A]. Is there any way that the structure of the term can be borken down and assigned to individual variables for processing like:  V = [Vector], Name = vivian, Courses= [taken(courses),...], Recommendations = [] ? I want to do this from within a script. I've been looking at the (unvi) =../2 and functor/3

Comment: univ it's the easier way to disassemble terms, but many times such 'disassembly' it's done at clause level. Pattern matching (i.e. select what clause to apply) it's data driven, and let you *control* how you use your data. I'm sorry I don't quite understand your last question... What you will do after you disassemble the student_profile? You will loose the context...

Comment: My plan once I have disassembled the student_profile is to use the first argument to calculate the euclidean distance and compare it to a database of student profiles (another file containing 47 similar predicates) to find the closest match and retrieve such similar student profile(s). What I'm  having trouble with is once I have read the file, I don't know how to extract the specific predicate (student_profile/4) from the such file. I will be repeating the procedure with several other profiles besides vivian and I'm working on procedure to do so. I'm pretty sure is something really simple..